# putting JSON into Google Charts

Tags: javascript, google-visualization

I'm trying to build a Google chart.

Current, I'm building an array using PHP's `json_encode($array)`. So,, my array variable looks like this:

```
var array = [{"name":"John Doe","userId":"12","count":"31"},{"name":"Catherine Cookson","userId":"212","count":"12"},{"name":"Lady Gaga","userId":"61","count":"20"}];
```

I'm passing it into a function which builds the chart:

```
drawRetChart(array);
```

Which then uses the data array:
    `data.addRows(array);`

However, when I try to load the chart, I get an error:
    Error: Every row given must be either null or an array.

How do I resolve this?

Answer (score 1):

You have a large array of objects, what you need is a large array of arrays.

```
var array = [[(key,val), (key,val), (key,val)],[array2], [array3]];
```